# Natural domain of $\frac f g$

Tags: functions

Question as follows

Find the natural domain of $\frac f g$

$f(x) = \sqrt {-x} $ 
$g(x) = -(x+3)^2$

My attempt so far:

$\frac {\sqrt {-x}}{-(x+3)^2}$

I am unsure of what you would do other than turn $\sqrt {-x} $ into $\frac 12(x)^ {-\frac 12}$

Would you find the lowest common demoninator and solve?

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing with $\frac12(x)^{-1/2}$? This isn't a calculus problem...

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

- Is it defined when the denominator is zero?
- Where is the square root defined? In the real line, can you take the square root of a negative number?

Comment: Undefined when the denominator is zero... unable to have a negative number for a square root so that would turn into a imaginary number?

Comment: @KyleMcCann Great! Now when is the denominator zero?

Comment: -3 as that would bring the +3 to zero and x would be minus infinity?

Comment: Yes. So you know that $x\neq-3$. What about the numerator? For what $x$ is it undefined? If you can answer that then you have solved the problem.